# How to place UIView on top of other UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

Right now I have a collectionView for which each cell contains a horizontal stackView. The stackView gets populated with a series of UIViews (rectangles), one for each day of a month - each cell corresponds to a month. I fill the stack views like so:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if collectionView == self.collectionView {
            ...
            return cell
        } else if collectionView == self.timeline {
            let index = indexPath.row
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM"
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: timelineMonthCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SNTimelineMonthViewCell
            let firstPost = posts.first?.timeStamp
            let month = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: index, to: firstPost!)
            print(dateFormatter.string(from: month!),dateFormatter.string(from: firstPost!),"month diff")
            for post in posts {
                print(post.timeStamp, "month diff")
            }
            cell.monthLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: month!)
            cell.monthLabel.textAlignment = .center

            if let start = month?.startOfMonth(), let end = month?.endOfMonth(), let stackView = cell.dayTicks {
                var date = start
                while date <= end {
                    let line = UIView()
                    if posts.contains(where: { Calendar.current.isDate(date, inSameDayAs: $0.timeStamp) }) {
                        line.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.67, blue:0.93, alpha:1.0)
                        let tapGuesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector (self.tapBar (_:)))
                        line.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        line.addGestureRecognizer(tapGuesture)
                        self.dayTicks[date] = line
                    } else {
                        line.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    }
                    stackView.addArrangedSubview(line)
                    date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: date)!
                }
            }
            return cell
        } else {
            preconditionFailure("Unknown collection view!")
        }
    }
```

Then, when the user stops scrolling a different collection view, I want to add a subview called arrowView ontop of the dayTick (see how self.dayTicks gets populated with the subviews of the stackView above).

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let currentIndex = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width
        let post = posts[Int(currentIndex)]
        for (_,tick) in self.dayTicks {
            tick.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
        }
        let day = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: post.timeStamp)
        let tick = self.dayTicks[day]
        let arrow = UIImage(named:"Tracer Pin")
        let arrowView = UIImageView(image: arrow)
//        arrowView.clipsToBounds = false
        print((tick?.frame.origin)!,"tick origin")
//        arrowView.frame.origin = (tick?.frame.origin)!
//        arrowView.frame.size.width = 100
//        arrowView.frame.size.height = 100
        tick?.addSubview(arrowView)

    }
```

This kind of works and it looks like this:

[image]

The red rectangle is added but it appears to the right of the dayTick, and it appears as a long thin rectangle. In actuality, the Tracer Pin image referenced looks like this:

[image]

Thats at least where the red color comes from but as you can see its stretching it weird and clipping everything thats not in a rectangular UIView space.

Now note that I commented out the 4 lines that set the size and origin of the arrowView as well as setting clipToBounds to false. When I uncomment these lines - the arrowView simply doesn't show up at all so I must be doing this wrong. What I want is to show something like this:

[image]

How can I put it directly on top like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using CALayer - thanks to @ouni's suggestion For some reason the CALayer seemed to draw directly on top of the view whereas a subview didn't. One key was unchecking the "Clip to bounds box on the collectionView cell itself (as opposed to the subview) - so that I could draw the flared base of the arrow outside of the collection view cell:

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == self.collectionView {
            print("is collection view")
            print(scrollView,"collection view")
            let currentIndex = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width
            let post = posts[Int(currentIndex)]
            for (_,tick) in self.dayTicks {
                tick.layer.sublayers = nil
            }
            let day = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: post.timeStamp)
            let tick = self.dayTicks[day]
            let arrowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            let path = UIBezierPath()
            let start_x = (tick?.bounds.origin.x)!
            let start_y = (tick?.bounds.minY)!
            let top_width = (tick?.bounds.width)!
            let tick_height = (tick?.bounds.height)!
            let tip_height = CGFloat(10)
            let tip_flare = CGFloat(10)
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: start_x, y: start_y))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start_x + top_width,y: start_y))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start_x + top_width,y: start_y + tick_height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start_x + top_width + tip_flare,y: start_y+tick_height+tip_height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start_x - tip_flare,y: start_y + tick_height + tip_height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: start_x,y: start_y+tick_height))
            path.close()
            arrowLayer.path = path.cgPath
            arrowLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red:0.99, green:0.13, blue:0.25, alpha:1.0).cgColor
            tick?.layer.addSublayer(arrowLayer)         
        } else {
            print(scrollView, "timeline collection view")
        }


    }
```

This draws the arrow on top of the subview beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

Another perspective might be to do this with CALayer.  Here are some clues (cut from another project) to help you discover a solution:

```
@IBInspectable open var slideIndicatorThickness: CGFloat = 5.0 {
    didSet {
        if slideIndicator != nil { slideIndicator.removeFromSuperlayer() }
        let slideLayer = CALayer()
        let theOrigin = CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y)
        let theSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(3.0), height: CGFloat(10.0)
        slideLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: theOrigin, size: theSize)
        slideLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        slideIndicator = slideLayer
        layer.addSublayer(slideIndicator)
    }
}

fileprivate var slideIndicator: CALayer!

fileprivate func updateIndicator() {
    // ..
    // Somehow figure out new frame, based on stack view's frame.
    slideIndicator.frame.origin.x = newOrigin
}
```

You may have to implement this on a subclass of UIStackView, or your own custom view that is a wrapper around UIStackView.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a fixed height on the arrowView. Could it be that the red triangle portion is under another view?

[Debug View Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQIDH.png)

Click the debug view hierarchy which is the second from right icon - it looks like 3 rectangles. Check to see if the whole image is there.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try that. why would it disappear when I add those 4 lines though?

Comment: I have learned that it still appears when I set             arrowView.clipsToBounds = false so its me setting the origin and/or size that messes with it?

Comment: Well when you define a UIView, it NEEDS an origin and size. When you comment those lines out, it disappears because it does not know where to be.
---
Taken from the documentation: You can also create views programmatically. When creating a view, you typically specify its initial size and position relative to its future superview. 
---
Checkout the "Creating a View" section near the top:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview?changes=_4

Comment: Try making the height of your arrowView equal to its parent instead of 100